# Charles Proxy and Interceptor are not tracking any http request in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, http-proxy, charles-proxy

I can't seem to get any activity showing on anything relating to HTTP/proxy requests in Ubuntu.

I downloaded Charles Proxy first, opened it, but shows nothing.
Then I tried Interceptor (Chrome extension), also nothing.

Having a look at my Ubuntu settings, it's entirely possible I'm supposed to configure something in here, in support of these options, but it's not documented at all.

[image]

**How I can go about listening to network requests, intercepting them and serving other/mock json when they happen?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure Chrome (or whatever the browser you use) to use the Charles Proxy's proxy (as far as I remember: `localhost:8888`). As this proxy is only running when you have CharlesProxy opened, you probably won't want to define it system wide.

The best option is to **use a proxy switch browser extension**, such as Switchy Omega ([chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif)) to be able to rapidly toggle on/off the proxy used by the browser.

Comment: cheers @LluisSunol currently thrashing my way through it, trying to map local vs JSON placeholder as a testing ground. Your answer/response was the missing piece.

Comment: Map local tool is really powerful when trying to develop or debug integrations with 3rd party agents. Glad to know it helped you!