# Charles proxy does not record

Tags: http, debugging, networking, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to use charles proxy, but after starting it as root, I still have only one sequence, but no more requests. why?

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the environment (operating system, browser, applications, etc.)?

Comment: Debian, Chrome, I wanted to debug the request between a smartphone running my expo application (react-native) and my expressjs backend

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your requester device does not have the proxy settings to reach CharlesProxy.

You can find instructions on how to configure your proxy settings on Chrome easily [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079618/charles-proxy-and-interceptor-are-not-tracking-any-http-request-in-ubuntu/58093131#58093131).